# How do I print a single label on a 4-page layout on Mac? (HP inkjet printer)

Tags: printing, layout, label, inkjet-printer

I am having a tough time locating information pertaining to my question.

I am a new seller on eBay and sometimes only need to print a single 4x5 label. The labels I have contain (4) 4x5 labels per page.

I know that when about to print, in print settings on my Mac, I can change to the correct layout of 4 copies per page, however, I don't want to print 4 copies of the same label and wish to keep the layout the same while only printing one on any of those 4 labels.

Hoping someone can cure my ignorance or provide a work-around! I appreciate your time and help!

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Is there a particular program (app) that you are using to make the labels?

Answer (score 1):

Use an app with label templates specific to your layout. Pages & Word can both do this, even though they are not specifically 'label printers'.

Avery, for instance give away templates in many formats for every label type they make. Look at your sheet, Paste one address in the next physically vacant square, print (as one whole page). File the rest of the sheet for next time.

BTW, inkjet ink is not waterproof. Make sure to seal your labels from the weather.

Avery templates link - https://www.avery.com/software/partners/apple-pages